# how can i interpret kernel density plots from classification?

Tags: classification, probability, density-estimation

all,

i have a classification problem where i am predicting likelihood of client defaulting on loan. i plotted the predicted probabilities from my model, and then plotted against the label '1' for default or 0 for non-default.

[image]

it is cut out here but y axis is the density. am i right to reason that this shows an exponential distribution, or that the fact the class 1 curve has a fat tail it shows that default is an extreme / unexpected event? woud you say class 1 is following any type of distribution?

compare this to the below:

[image]

doesn't the second graph show that the model isn't that good at distinguishing between class 0 and class 1?

Answer (score 1):

In both graph it show that the model will not perform very well on the classification task as the probability distribution of the model overlaps significantly. A good model will have almost seperated curve for each class. Adding more feature will help the model differentiate between curves.

Comment: but can you comment on anything about the likelihood of default, could you say it suggests defaults are extreme

Comment: Except near the peak of green curve the default will be red class as it has fat tail

Comment: does this indicate a imbalanced problem or not?

Comment: Yeah partly. But your model should be trained with more dimensions or more differentiable feature so that it can distinguish

Comment: sorry to add do both plots indicate imbalcned probem? what does area under the kde show?

Comment: Second one is not imbalanced problem. First one partly. Area is your confidence level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110087/discussion-between-maths12-and-srj).